# compare the elements of one list with the elements of another list in prolog

Tags: list, recursion, prolog

First of all, I am completely a beginner at Prolog.

I am trying to compare each element of a list with each element of another list. By compare, I mean sending these 2 elements to a predicate(conflicts) I wrote. So far, I got this:

```
%iterate over the first list
cmp_list([],_,_).
cmp_list([X|Y],[A|B],Result):-
      cmp_list_inner(X,[A|B],Result),
      cmp_list(Y,[A|B],Result).

%iterate over the second list
cmp_list_inner(_,[],_).
cmp_list_inner(X,[A|B],S):-
    not(conflicts(X,A)), %compare
    cmp_list_inner(X,B,[X-A|S]).%if okay, add their combination, i.e X-A to the main list which will be returned
```

The predicate cmp_list stands for the recursion of outer list, whereas the one with inner stands for inner list.
cmp_list(firstlist, secondlist, new list after the combination which will be returned.)

This doesn't work! Even though it adds the values for a single element in the first value to the main list, it doesn't append the second comparison(for the second element in the first list) to the main list which will be returned. Result should be in the form of:
[X1-Y1], [X1-Y2], [X2-Y1], [X2-Y2].... where Xs are from the first list and Ys are from the second list.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need one simple predicate:

```
cmp_list([], [], []).              % cmp_list succeeds for two empty lists
cmp_list([H1|T1], [H2|T2], [H1-H2|R]) :-
    % cmp_list of [H1|T1] and [H2|T2] succeeds if...
    \+ conflicts(H1, H2),          % conflicts fails for H1 and H2
    cmp_list(T1, T2, R).           % cmp_list succeeds for T1 and T2, result R

% Otherwise, cmp_list fails (e.g., lists are diff length)
```

A little more compact would be to use the built-in predicate, `maplist`:

```
cmp_list(L1, L2, R) :-                % cmp_list succeeds on L1, L2 if...
    maplist(no_conflicts, L1, L2, R). % no_conflicts succeeds for every
                                      %   corresponding pair of L1, L2 elements

no_conflicts(X, Y, X-Y) :- \+ conflicts(X-Y).
```

If you just want to capture all the corresponding pairs that don't conflict and ignore the rest, then:

```
cmp_list([], _, []).
cmp_list([_|_], [], []).
cmp_list([H1|T1], [H2|T2], R) :-
    (   conflicts(H1, H2)
    ->  cmp_list(T1, T2, R)
    ;   R = [H1-H2|R1],
        cmp_list(T1, T2, R1)
    ).
```

This uses the "if-then-else" pattern in Prolog formed by grouping `->` with `;`. This will create a result that looks like, `[x1-y1, x3-y3, ...]`. You can choose however you want to form your result elements by changing this line:

```
R = [H1-H2|R1]
```

For example, `R = [[H1,H2]|R1]` would yield a result that looks like, `[[x1,y1], [x3,y3], ...]`.

---

For the more general problem (*i.e.*, the one you were really looking for :)), I'll start with the original code but modify it where it's needed:

```
%iterate over the first list
cmp_list([], _, []).
cmp_list([X|T], L2, Result):-
    cmp_list_inner(X, L2, R1),
    cmp_list(T, L2, R2),
    append(R1, R2, Result).

%iterate over the second list
cmp_list_inner(_, [], []).
cmp_list_inner(X, [A|B], R) :-
    (   conflicts(X, A)
    ->  cmp_list_inner(X, B, R)
    ;   R = [X-A|T],
        cmp_list_inner(X, B, T)
    ).
```

Comment: Thanks! The result should be like [X1-Y3],[X2-Y4], [X5-Y1] etc.
where Xs are in list1 and Ys are in list2. It should be a list of non conflicting pairs and pairs are all the combination of list1's elements and list2's elements. Doesn't your solution check index by index? I am trying to compare X1 with Y1,Y2,Y3.. X2 with Y1,Y2,Y3... etc.

Comment: I mean, it shouldn't fail if the lists are different lengths.

Comment: @user3450161 do you want it to capture all that match then, and ignore those that don't?

Comment: Exactly! Any pair of non conflicting elements should be in the Result in the form of [X1-Y3] etc.

Comment: Thanks so that I learned if else in Prolog. However, it is still trying to match the lists with respect to their indexes. After I call the predicate, I got something like:
[X1-Y1],[X2-Y2] whereas I should have something like [X1-Y1][X1-Y2][X2-Y1][X2-Y2]. What am I doing wrong? Sorry I bother you but this is my first attempt at Prolog.

Comment: @user3450161 Oh I see. Sorry that wasn't clear. You're trying to match corresponding pair of elements between the lists? And is it possible there could be more than one match from say, one element from the first list, with multiple elements in the second? I may have to kill my answer since it doesn't really answer your question, then...

Comment: Yes it is possible. E.g if length(list1) = 3 and length(list2) = 4 then there should be 12 comparisons. Those that don't conflict, should be in the Result as a non conflicting pair.

Comment: @user3450161 OK, if more than one match is possible between an element in the first list and various elements in the second, then this predicate could have multiple solution sets, some longer than others. My answer above doesn't do this at all so I think I might delete it for now.

Comment: Yes but still thank you so much! I would be grateful if you have a solution for this question.

Comment: @false, yes you're right. I knew it had that little "flaw" but ultimately it wasn't the answer the OP was looking for anyway.

Comment: So dou you have a solution for the Result in the form of matching one element from first list with the multiple elements in the second?
e.g: [X1-Y1][X1-Y2][X2-Y1][X2-Y2]...

Comment: If you can still edit your answer with your updated version, I can try to fix it, at least I can try. Thanks!

Comment: @user3450161 done, and I got rid of my initial problem; but I'm not sure it produces all of the valid solutions depending upon scenario.